# Badge design in xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to imitate the icons shown in the image below.

[image]

I tried the same in XML but I am unable to achieve it.
Please guide me.

Comment: Please attach your image here.

Comment: [1]: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4999
  [2]: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4670
  [3]: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4794

Comment: The small one (the badge) is simply a TextView. And place it over any other View (the bigger one "under" it - meaning on the Z axis). Just as easy as this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the answer myself from this site - http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/01/adding-badge-item-count-to-android-button.html